# How to trigger cypress after:run after tests finish execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, report, metadata

I'm using `cypress` + `multiple-cucumber-html-report` to generate a report after execution. There is the possibility to add custom data to the report such as execution start and end time.

I assume this information somehow comes from cypress as part of the result meta data.

I tried to put results in json file after the run finishes, by adding it to the cypress config file:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress';
import * as fs from 'fs';

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {

  on('after:run', async (results) => {
    if (results) {
      fs.mkdirSync("cypress/.run", { recursive: true });
      fs.writeFile("cypress/.run/results.json", JSON.stringify(results), (err) => {
        if (err)
          console.log(err);
        else {
          console.log("Successful results has been written");
        }
      });
    }
  })

  return config;
}

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents,
    experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true
  },
});
```

then read these results in the report generation file:

```
const report = require('multiple-cucumber-html-reporter');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('cypress/.run/results.json', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    var runInfos = JSON.parse(data);
    report.generate({
        jsonDir: './cypress/result/',
        reportPath: './cypress/report/',
        metadata:{
            browser: {
                name: runInfos.browserName,
                version: runInfos.browserVersion
            },
            device: 'Cypress',
            platform: {
                name: mapOs(runInfos.osName)
            }
        },
        customData: {
            title: 'Run info',
            data: [
                {label: 'Project', value: 'project'},
                {label: 'Execution Start Time', value: new Date(runInfos.startedTestsAt).toLocaleString()},
                {label: 'Execution End Time', value: new Date(runInfos.endedTestsAt).toLocaleString()}
            ]
        }
    });
});
```

unfortunately the `after:run` was never triggered, and not even throwing an error.

Comment: It works fine for me in run mode, both Cypress 10.11.0 and v12.5.0.

Comment: Thanks, @Paolo for the confirmation. I'll revisit my configuration again.

Comment: open mode and `experimentalInteractiveRunEvents`, not so much - some error in the terminal I can't decipher.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the docs on [After Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api#Syntax)

> When running via `cypress open`, the `after:run` event only fires if the `experimentalInteractiveRunEvents` flag is enabled.

Unfortunately, from the look of your config sample you must be using an older version of Cypress (pre v10).

To make this more useful, upgrade Cypress the use the flag mentioned above like this:

```js
// cypress.config.js

const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:run', (results) => {
        /* ... */
      })
    },
    experimentalInteractiveRunEvents: true,   // here is the flag, not documented in the configuration page
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm actually using cypress10 and I have the `on('after:run', ....` as part of the setupNodeEvents function. The only difference I can see is `experimentalInteractiveRunEvents` is it necessary for triggering it?

Comment: it seems that this flag is _only_ used when in interactive mode `npx cypress open`, I tried both `npx cypress open` and `run` with and without the flag, still doesn't seem to trigger the `after:run`

Comment: Well the flag is only *necessary* when trying to perform `after:run`  in interactive mode. In run mode, it always fires after... the `cypress run`. I don't know if your `async` is spoiling things - it is certainly no use in front of the callback, since nothing is awaited.